# Given a rational decimal number, how to determine its smallest dividend and divisor?

Tags: algorithms

Given rational decimal number for example $0.25 =\frac{1}{4}$

is there an algorithmic approach or a formula to determine its smallest numerator and denominator?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this site. For example, you're expected to share your work, something that shows that you put some effort on your own before asking for help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dividend. The algorithm you are seeking is probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid's_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write the number as a quotient of two integers. You'll have to cases:

- The decimal expansion is finite. For example $$.1487123$$

What you do is write it as $$\frac{1487123}{10000000}$$

- The decimal expansion is periodic. For example $$.1487\overline{123}$$

Then you write it as

$$\frac{1487 + .\overline{123}}{10000}$$

and

$$.\overline{123} = \frac{123}{999}$$

Substitute that and simplify.

Once you have the number written as the quotient of two integers, divide both numerator and denominator by its greatest common divisor, which you may calculate with the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you, really informative and detailed answer!